# Show content added by current user

Tags: users, nodes

In user permissions i let users with editor role "Access the content overview page". And this page showing them all added content. I can make a view with this user added content, but i want to achieve this with "Find content" page. How can i achieve that? I want users to show only the content they added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible with the Find Content page. You may have to resort to making a View to accomplish the task. I've created several views for the same purpose, and actually prefer it as I can create my own admin links (edit, delete, view, publish, etc.) customized to what my goal for the page is.

Comment: and how can i put edit or delete links of node in view?

Comment: I usually display this type of data in a table using fields. When you go to add a new field, there are options for edit and delete links (called "Content: Delete link" and "Content: Edit link"). These will automatically work for each piece of content shown. I will usually add both fields and set them to "Exclude from Display", then add a "Global: Custom text" field and add both the edit and delete fields into it so that they can show in the same table cell (this is done by using the "Replacement Patterns" in the custom text field). And you can do the same for any other type of link.